# XNA Collision detection on a list of objects

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach, xna, collision-detection

I'm trying to detect collision on a list of enemy objects, however it's only working on the last created object. I've tried both :

```
for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Count; i++)
{
    if (IntersectsPixel(player.rectangle, player.textureData, enemies[i].rectangle, enemies[i].textureData))
    {
        touched = true;
    }
    else
    {
        touched = false;
    }
}
```

And :

```
foreach (Enemy enemy in enemies)
{
    if (IntersectsPixel(player.rectangle, player.textureData, enemy.rectangle, enemy.textureData))
    {
        touched = true;
    }
    else
    {
        touched = false;
    }
}
```

Both of which I'm putting in the Update method. The enemies are created every few seconds so i know the detection works, but once the next one appears, the last one stops working...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you check last item only, you must break loop, when `IntersectsPixel` true and process the object

```
for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Count; i++)
{
    if (IntersectsPixel(player.rectangle, player.textureData, enemies[i].rectangle, enemies[i].textureData))
    {
        touched = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

or use linq to collect all thus objects:

```
var resTrue = enemies.Where(x=>x.IntersectsPixel(player.rectangle, player.textureData, enemies[i].rectangle, enemies[i].textureData)).ToList();
var resFalse = enemies.Where(x=>!x.IntersectsPixel(player.rectangle, player.textureData, enemies[i].rectangle, enemies[i].textureData)).ToList();
```

Comment: use linq examples and process all item in the group

Comment: one word... Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you implement a property `bool Touched` in `class Enemy`?

That way, you could change your code like this:

```
if (/*check for collision*/)
    enemy.Touched = true;
```

Better yet, instead of `Touched`, implement a method `OnTouched(/*arguments*/)`, so you can do this:

```
if (/*check for collision*/)
    enemy.OnTouched(/*arguments*/); // Which would perform any and all necessary actions on the touched object
```